# Unity 2018 or 2019 reduce size of APK or .ipa file

Tags: android, ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, apk

I have made a game for mobile using Unity 2018 (now using 2019) and when i generate the APK it comes to a total of 97 MB in iOS its more it comes to a size of almost 200MB (.ipa file).

I have searched around the web and after doing the suggested steps i did not succeed in reducing the build size,

Can anyone tell me how to reduce the APK and Xcode build to a normal size?

Again currently im using Unity 2019 but i would like to know hot to accomplish this in unity 2018xx as well.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no normal size of the build. It just depends on your project.

It's quite difficult things to optimize the app size.

Did you check the unity3d docs?

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ReducingFilesize.html

https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/memory-management-in-unity

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/iphone-playerSizeOptimization.html

If then, I think the binary contains the wrong resources.

With [Android Studio apk Analyzer](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/apk-analyzer) will help you to find the hint of optimizing.

Yes, optimize the build is quite difficult things. I hope you could find a hint of the optimize.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply if someone has a more detailed explanation it will be most helpful again thanks for the reply.